# Accessibility Angular5 with aria-live

Tags: angular, accessibility, uiaccessibility

We have an application on Angular 6 and have to implement accessibility. I added aria-live="polite" in angular-components, but Chromevox reader interrupts itself when data is loading. Because we're using sockets and get responses in random order.
Is it a solution to set the order in which reader should read components inner text?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by chromevox is "interrupting itself". Do you mean it stops speaking? I would first check with JAWS and NVDA to see if it works well. Chromevox is a last resort for testing. Lots of things work on JAWS/NVDA that don't work with chromevox.

And just to make sure you're using it properly, [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) should be used when you have components that are updating dynamically and you want those changes announced to screen readers.  "Polite" is the right value for that attribute unless on the rare occasions you need the change announced immediately, then "assertive" should be used.

Even less used should be [`role="alert"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#alert), which has an implicit `aria-live="assertive"` and also might tie in with the platform's alert messaging system and will often announce "alert" pre-pended to your change.